# Getting GetResponse() of HttpWebRequest gives ProtocolViolationException

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I'm tried make an http request to google page,but it not works and give an `ProtocolViolationException` when I try get the Response.

Here's my code:

```
 public CookieCollection GetTempCookies()
        {

            CookieContainer MyCookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            CookieCollection cookies = GetGalxAndGaps();
            string postData = "foo=baa&etc.."; 
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
            int postLength = data.Length;

            for (int i = 0, max = cookies.Count; i != max; i++)
            {
                Cookie tempCookie = cookies[i];
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie(tempCookie.Name, tempCookie.Value, tempCookie.Path);
                MyCookieContainer.Add(new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth"), cookie);
            }

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com");
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.ContentLength = postLength;
            req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            req.CookieContainer = MyCookieContainer;

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse(); // <- this cause the exception 
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            stream.Write(data, 0, postLength);
            return response.Cookies;

        }
```

Can someone point my error?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to *write* to the *response* stream. You should write to the *request* stream, and then get the response:

```
using (Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse())
{
    return response.Cookies;
}
```

Comment: Hello, John! Thanks for your answer. 
the first problem was solved, but now I'm getting other error from request response:  `The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.`. 

What am I doing wrong? 
another question:the google have an simple API, that not use the Oauth autentication protocol? this because I'm writing a desktop application. 
I need to do work with orkut pages.

Comment: @Kakashi: Sorry for not seeing your previous reply. I don't know, I'm afraid - I've never worked with this API. Even though I work for Google, please don't take any of my comments as being "from" Google :) Are you sure you shouldn't be using the full "ServiceLoginAuth" URL instead of just accounts.google.com?

Comment: Very late but for anyone looking "Method Not Allowed" means just that. The API you're accessing doesn't support the method. E.g you're trying to POST when it only accepts GET and vice versa.